# How can I use callback that returns Promise?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have function:

```
export const paramsFactory = (params: paramsType) => {
  return ...
}
```

In another component I have the same function but after **return ...** it also contains `await getPageInfo({ page: 1 })`.
So I need pass callback as a second param to this function. And how to use it correctly?
I have something like that:

```
    export const paramsFactory = (params: paramsType, callback?: () => Promise<void>) => {
      return async (...) => { 
        ...
        if (callback) {
          await callback()
        }
      }
    }
```

await callback() as a part of return statement.
When I use it `paramsFactory(params, getPageInfo({ page: 1 }))` I get

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '() => Promise'.   Type 'Promise'
> provides no match for the signature '(): Promise'.

Comment: `await callback()`?

Comment: "*after return ... it also contains await getPageInfo({ page: 1 })*" code after a return statement doesn't run. If it's really *after* the return, then it's probably an error. If it's *part of* the return statement, then you just need to execute the callback. Although the fact that it is `Promise<void>` suggests it shouldn't be part of an expression, since you cannot use its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```js
paramsFactory(params, () => getPageInfo({ page: 1 }))
```

Comment: it works, but I get `TS2345: Argument of type '() => undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Promise<void>'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'`

Comment: @Stanislay Kim sorry it was my fault i updated the answer